# Load multiple content in same page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i have check about this question. But still stuck, I am using wordpress and want to insert it in some page or post.

So i have searched and see this code `http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/NuwE6/` but when i transfer to html or insert in `http://liveweave.com/8PQ77Q` and nothing happen?

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: jsfiddle is including jQuery for you, liveweave isn't. If you include jQuery in liveweave it works as expected. Remember to include jQuery on the page in your wordpress site too.

Comment: @iblamefish thank you that work. Your sincerely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have jQuery included in your page. For instance, on LiveWeave, you need to add jQuery as a library to see your code working. Just check you have jQuery loaded on your Wordpress website.